# errors in a simple python code in basic function which do power for the recieved number

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

I am learning python, this is a basic code and i dont know why it doesn't work. for the **variable "index"** i have the error "Unused variable 'index'". and for the **command while** i have the error "Unreachable code".

```
def power(base, pow):
        result = 1
        for index in range(pow):
            result *= base
        return result
    
        while input("would you like to continue?  ") == "yes":
            print(power(input("enter the base: \n"), input("enter the power: \n")))
```

Comment: Those seem like IDE warnings, not actual code errors

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your code. You are getting compiler warnings, not errors. Currently, while loop in your code won't ever be executed. Just take the while loop outside of the function declaration to get rid of the warnings.

```
def power(base, pow):
    result = 1
    for index in range(pow):
        result *= base
    return result

while input("would you like to continue?  ") == "yes":
    print(power(input("enter the base: \n"), input("enter the power: \n")))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Mark Jacobson mentioned, these are IDE warnings. Your code will still run.

```
def power(base, pow):
        result = 1
        for index in range(pow):  # you set index to a value, but never use it
            result *= base
        return result   # your function will exit here, so the code below will never run
    
        while input("would you like to continue?  ") == "yes":
            print(power(input("enter the base: \n"), input("enter the power: \n")))
```

As @Aniket mentioned in the other answer, you can just remove the while loop if you don't need it or unindent so it's not in the function.

The warning is not hurting the program, but if you want to remove the warning, iterate using `pow`.

```
def power(base, pow):
        result = 1
        while pow > 0:
            result *= base
            pow -= 1
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You code need slight modification:

```
def power(base, pow):
        result = 1
        for index in range(pow):
            result *= base
        return result
    
while input("would you like to continue?  ") == "yes":
    print(power(int(input("enter the base: \n")), int(input("enter the power: \n"))))
```

Comment: Nothing changed @Surya Lohia

Answer (score 0):

```py
def power(base, pow):
        result = 1
        for index in range(pow):
            result *= base
        return result
    
while (input("would you like to continue?  ") == "yes"):
    print(power(int(input("enter the base: \n")), int(input("enter the power: \n"))))
```

Comment: Hi there, it is often useful to provide some amount of explanation at all, especially with such little difference between your answer and the question itself.

Comment: I have brought the while loop to the function level to pass the value. Type casting is most important because we know that we can't do any any calculation in the form of string..